# Does a Virtual Machine have to interpret Bytecode or can it interpret the VM's assembly directly?

Tags: assembly, go, bytecode, vm-implementation

I am planning on implementing a VM in Go. I saw tutorials where people designed their own type of assembly for their VM, but the Virtual Machine didn't execute the assembly code directly. They encoded each of the instructions for their VM assigning them each a number and forming a special bytecode for their machine.
Is it better to interpret the bytecode or can you interpret the assembly code and achieve the same results?

Comment: If you're planning on only supporting one platform, e.g. x86, there is no immediate need for abstracting the instructions. So it depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I would like my VM to be able to run platform independently.

Comment: Sorry for being cloudy, I meant the guest platforms. Do you want to support different platforms as guests?

Comment: It's not a VM for an operating system. It's a VM for a programming language interpreter. Thanks for your answers though!

Comment: Sorry I just have one more question. Does my custom bytecode have to be turned into 1's and 0's or could my VM execute the instructions themselves without turning them into 1's and 0's ?

Comment: It is supposed to execute the instructions. That's what VMs do, simulate an artificial environment.

Comment: When you say "or can you interpret the assembly code", are you referring to the textual description of the program in bytecode assembly? Or machine level assembly code?

Comment: @NickJohnson I'm talking about the the textual description of the assembly code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use your VM in different guest platforms, then *yes*.

The advantage that bytecode gives you is *portability* (therefore the alternate naming *"p-code"*, which is short for *"portable code"*).

If you plan to use your VM in different platforms, you should go for bytecode. Then you would have to take care of compiling the program into bytecode instructions and the VM would take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Language runtimes execute compiled bytecode rather than textual assembly instructions because parsing text is slow. A well written runtime can parse and execute a bytecode instruction in a few processor cycles - but parsing textual statements requires a lot more work. The sanest way to do it would be to parse the entire assembly file and store it in memory in an intermediate representation - which is exactly what bytecode is. Further, some things such as jumps and addressing only really make sense in bytecode.

Instead of thinking as bytecode as a binary representation of assembly, consider assembly as a textual representation of bytecode.